# Loading external packages in Common Lisp with SLIME on Debian

Tags: debian, common-lisp, package, slime, sbcl

I'm using SBCL 1.0.56 on Debian squeeze, with cl-swank/slime
1:20120420-2 (Debian version number). These are all the current
versions in unstable.

I've been having problems with loading third party CL packages. The
documentation for using CL on Debian (and indeed the more general CL
usage documentation on Linux) is sketchy, contradictory, and
out-of-date, so I'll summarize what I know. Here is where I am at.

Debian installs binary packages (example, cl-split-sequence) in
`/usr/share/common-lisp/source`. In the case of split-sequence, this is
`/usr/share/common-lisp/source/cl-split-sequence`.

The .asd file (here
`/usr/share/common-lisp/source/cl-split-sequence/split-sequence.asd`),
which, as I understand it, gives instructions to the CL implementation
about version and dependencies, looks like

```
;;; -*- Lisp -*- mode
(defpackage #:split-sequence-system (:use #:cl #:asdf))
(in-package :split-sequence-system)

(defsystem :split-sequence
    :version "20011114.1"
    :components ((:file "split-sequence")))
```

Now, when running slime, entering the following two lines at the REPL
works without a problem

```
(require :split-sequence)
(split-sequence:SPLIT-SEQUENCE  #\, "foo,bar")
```

The `(require :split-sequence)` invokes (I think) the builtin copy of
ASDF inside SBCL, which presumably looks at `split-sequence.asd`. This
is probably SBCL-specific, see [Common Lisp in Debian Manual Chapter 3 -Libraries](http://pkg-common-lisp.alioth.debian.org/clid/clid.html/chlibs.html).
It is worth noting that this page, which is as useful and detailed as
anything I've come across, makes frequent reference to CLC (Common
Lisp Controller), but it seems Debian is moving away from this. See
[Redesign of Common Lisp
Controller](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.debian.alioth.common-lisp/2431),
which I don't fully understand. At any rate, none of the documented
commands for using CLC work for me.  However, CLC is still available
on Debian. Also, the users mailing list is dead - see [The Clc-users
Archives](http://lists.alioth.debian.org/pipermail/clc-users/)

The first time `(require :split-sequence)` is invoked, it is compiled,
and (on my system, possibly Debian-specific) the resulting `fasl` is
placed in

`~/.cache/common-lisp/sbcl-1.0.56.0.debian-linux-x86/usr/share/common-lisp/source/cl-split-sequence/split-sequence.fasl`

I.e. the file is placed under the cache in a filesystem mirroring the
location of the original source. The obvious question is, how does the
system know where to look for the package? This is one thing I am not
sure about. It looks like the search paths should be given in
`/etc/common-lisp/source-registry.conf.d`, which is part of the ASDF
Debian package, but the closest thing is
`01-common-lisp-controller.conf`, which is just

```
(:directory  #p"/usr/share/common-lisp/systems/")
```

Maybe this is hard-wired somewhere, but I'd like to know.

Anyway, once this ASDF file is in the cache, it is not compiled again,
but the REPL doesn't see it after slime starts up unless one does
`require` again.

Now, if I put the lines

```
(require :split-sequence)
(split-sequence:SPLIT-SEQUENCE  #\, "foo,bar")
```

In a file, say `seq.lisp`, and load it into the REPL with C-c C-k, I get
an error and traceback, starting with

```
The name "SPLIT-SEQUENCE" does not designate any package.
   [Condition of type SB-KERNEL:SIMPLE-PACKAGE-ERROR]
```

so I conclude that the package has not been loaded correctly. I tried variations like

```
(asdf:oos 'asdf:load-op :split-sequence)
```

and

```
(asdf:load-system :split-sequence)
```

but no dice. Weirdly, suppose we just have the line

```
(require :split-sequence)
```

in a file - call this `require.lisp` for clarity.  Then loading
`require.lisp` doesn't give an error, and then typing

```
(split-sequence:SPLIT-SEQUENCE  #\, "foo,bar")
```

at the REPL works! However, without loading `require.lisp`, typing the
preceding line doesn't work at the REPL.

So, in conclusion, how can one successfully load a package in a
script?  I'd also be interested in the issue mentioned above, about
how ASDF is finding the `/usr/share/common-lisp/source/` location, but
that is more a side issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-k</kbd> compiles the source file and then loads the compiled file.

A Lisp source file contains definitions and calls. The file compiler walks through the file and creates code for it. But it does not execute it.

If your file contains a call to `REQUIRE`, it is not executed during compilation. It will be executed if you later load the compiled file. If the next Lisp form in the file then is using some package which would be available after the call to `REQUIRE`, it is just not there during compilation, since the `REQUIRE` has not been executed yet - thus the error during reading while compiling.

There are basically two solutions to that:

- execute all the necessary `REQUIRE` operations before you compile a particular file using the required functionality.
- execute the `REQUIRE` statement during compilation. That's where `EVAL-WHEN :COMPILE-TOPLEVEL` tells the compile to execute the subforms during compilation.

`#+:sbcl(foo)` means that (foo) is read only when `:SBCL` is a symbol present in the list `CL:*FEATURES*`. It is used so that the compiler sees this code only when it is SBCL.

The compilation of Common Lisp code takes more care to prepare, because:

- one can execute Lisp code during file compilation and thus change the behavior of the file compiler.
- packages (which are namespaces for symbols), which are used in the source code, need to be known to the file compiler's reader.

Comment: Thanks Rainer, that's a very clear explanation. How much of the script I quoted is actually necessary? What does the `#+:sbcl` do if anything?

Comment: Answering my own question - apparently not much. Just `(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (require :split-sequence))

(print (split-sequence:SPLIT-SEQUENCE  #\, "foo,bar"))` works.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the following post, [Zach Beane's Blog - Making a small Common Lisp project](http://xach.livejournal.com/130040.html), which had a link to http://common-lisp.net/~loliveira/ediware/ediware.lisp

Copying the code at that top of that file works. So running C-c C-k in slime on this file loads `split-sequence`, and runs the code `int (split-sequence:SPLIT-SEQUENCE  #\, "foo,bar"))`

```
#+:sbcl
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (require :asdf))

(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (asdf:oos 'asdf:load-op :split-sequence))

(defpackage #:seq
  (:use #:cl #:split-sequence))
(in-package #:seq)

(print (split-sequence:SPLIT-SEQUENCE  #\, "foo,bar"))
```

However, I've no idea what these magical incantations do. Would anyone care to explain, perhaps in another answer? I'm putting this in an answer, because it is an answer to the question, but it is not complete, because I don't understand why it works. I'll gladly accept an explanation of this script.